# Truncating the file in c++

Tags: c++, file, file-io, logging, filestream

I was writing a program in C++ and wonder if anyone can help me with the situation explained here.

1. Suppose, I have a log file of about size 30MB, I have copied last 2MB of file to a buffer within the program.
2. I delete the file (or clear the contents) and then write back my 2MB to the file.

Everything works fine till here. But, the concern is I read the file (the last 2MB) and clear the file (the 30MB file) and then write back the last 2MB.
To much of time will be needed if in a scenario where I am copying last 300MB of file from a 1GB file.

Does anyone have an idea of making this process simpler?

When having a large log file the following reasons should and will be considered.

**Disk Space:** Log files are uncompressed plain text and consume large amounts of space.
Typical compression reduce the file size by 10:1. However a file cannot be compressed 
when it is in use (locked). So a log file must be rotated out of use.

**System resources:** Opening and closing a file regularly will consume lots of system 
resources and it would reduce the performance of the server.

**File size:** Small files are easier to backup and restore in case of a failure.

I just do not want to copy, clear and re-write the last specific lines to a file. Just a simpler process.... :-)

EDIT: Not making any inhouse process to support log rotation. 
**logrotate is the tool.**

Comment: As a side note, if this is all your program is going to do, this operation is possible with simple *nix commands, if you're on a *nix system. `dd` can copy the required chunk out to a secondary file, and it's a delete-rename from there...

Comment: @Thanatos As a side note there are several ports of the GNU utilities to Windows.

Comment: e.g., `tail --bytes=2MB file_name | xargs -0 echo > file_name`

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest an slightly different approach.

1. Create a new temporary file
2. Copy the required data from the original file to the temporary file
3. Close both files
4. Delete the original file
5. Rename the temp file to the same name as the original file

To improve the performance of the copy, you can copy the data in chunks, you can play around with the chunk size to find the optimal value.

Comment: Let me give a try right now!... concerned about copying 300MB file out from a 1GB file.... :( I will benchmark it....

Comment: The temporary file has a certain robustness to it if something goes wrong, and is a good idea, +1. As an example, `gparted` will actually change chunksizes until it finds a good value when copying/moving partitions.

Comment: It takes *almost* same time as deleting the entire file and writing back. Could I try truncating the log file? will do little research.

Answer (score 1):

If this is your file before:

```
-----------------++++
```

Where `-` is what you don't want and `+` is what you do want, the most portable way of getting:

```
++++
```

...is just as you said. Read in the section you want (`+`), delete/clear the file (as with `fopen(... 'wb') or something similar` and write out the bit you want (`+`).

Anything more complicated requires OS-specific help, and isn't portable. Unfortunately, I don't believe any major OS out there has support for what you want. There might be support for "truncate *after* position X" (a sort of `head`), but not the `tail` like operation you're requesting.

Such an operation would be difficult to implement, as varying blocksizes on filesystems (if the filesystem *has* a block size) would cause trouble. At best, you'd be limited to cutting on blocksize boundaries, but this would be harry. This is such a rare case, that this is probably why such a procudure is not directly supported.

Comment: Agreed!... Ok suppose I reverse the file and truncate the last 28MB... What do you reckon? And can you give me a clue to truncate the file? (the tail part itself)

Answer (score 1):

A better approach might be not to let the file grow that big but rather use rotating log files with a set maximum size per log file and a maximum number of old files being kept.

Answer (score 0):

If you can control the writing process, what you probably want to do here is to write to the file like a [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). That way you can keep the last X bytes of data without having to do what you're suggesting at all.

Even if you can't control the writing process, if you can at least control what file it writes to, then maybe you could get it to write to a [named pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe). You could attach your own program at the end of this named pipe that writes to a [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) as discussed.